# Use class to represent foreign key / join table in Android SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, join

I need to use classes to represent entities in database, here are some information:

=== TABLEs ===

**SHOP**
shop_id(primary)
name
owner

**FAVOURITES LIST**
fav_id(primary)
list_name

**(JOIN)FAV_SHOPS**
fav_id(primary)
shop_id(primary)

If I use a class Shop to represent shop entity, and FavShops to represent fav_shops, FavShops is written as below:

```
class FavShop {
    int fav_id;
    String list_name;
    NSSet<Shop> shops;
}
```

Then how do I retrieve fav_shops from database in SQLite(Android)? I'll be appreciated if any one can provide some SQL statement, I also need to save the list to database, say, I added another shop to FavShop "My Favourites", how do I save it back to database?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stack overflow, but how do I actually ACCEPT an answer?

Comment: Clicking and highlighting the green tick next to the answer that is correct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOIN to get your FavShops table..

```
SELECT * FROM fav_shops INNER JOIN favourites_list ON fav_shops.fav_id = favourite_list.fav_id WHERE favourite_list.fav_id = <YOUR_LIST_ID>
```

You can put whatever clause you need in your WHERE (shop_id = ?, list_name = ?, etc..)

And to insert a new row in the fav_shops table

```
INSERT INTO fav_sops (fav_id, shop_id) values ('My Favourites', <A_SHOP_ID>);
```

Comment: Also, if I use Android and SQLite, is there any specific method like SQLiteDatabase.query that wraps SQL with a method for "INSERT"? And do I need to do something like flush buffer to make sure data has been written to the actual db or do I just close db at the end and it will be saved locally?